# Is there a way to recognize when text is dragged and dropped into an input element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Usually, when a marked piece of text is dragged and dropped into a HTML input element, the marked text is copied at the cursor location (and added to any existing text) in that input field. I would like to change that behavior using jQuery such that it resembles the behavior of (e.g.) the Firefox address field, that is:

- Text can be added and modified by typing (as usual).
- When text is dragged from outside and dropped into the input element, all existing text within the input is replaced by the dragged text.
- When text is dragged and dropped within the input filed, then the dragged text is moved at the cursor's location. (nice-to-have feature, but not that important)

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

It seems to me that to this end, I need to recognize some kind of "drag-and-drop" event and access the dragged text, although I don't know if this is even possible. A (non-functional) mock-up of the scenario I have in mind would look like the following:

HTML:

```
<p>drag-and-drop text into this:</p>
<input id="giveittome" value="some text"></input>
<p>other text</p>
<p>more text</p>
<p>whatever</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#giveittome').on('drag-and-drop' , function (event) {
    $(this).val(event.getDraggedText());
});
```

[source @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VYDCU/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: (it will work in most modern browsers)

```
$('input').on('keydown change paste drop',function(event) {
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(_this.value, event.type);
    }, 0); //this timeout is necessary  to get the value
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/7skY7/

Comment: Thought so. ;) HTML5 brings some nifty features.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the instant help. The 'drop' event works actually quite great for my purpose: http://jsfiddle.net/VYDCU/1/. Hooray for HTML5!